# Ada: interfacing with Matlab

Tags: matlab, ada, scientific-computing

since Ada doesn't possess any good libraries for scientific computing, I was wondering if anyone has been able to use Matlab mathematical functions such as eig (for calculations of eigenvalues and eigenvectors) within Ada.

I see that some interfaces exist for simulink and Ada. But I'm not a user of Simulink. I would like just to be able to use Matlab mathematical functions through perhaps Ada functions and procedures.

PS: In earlier Ada documents there were lots of talks and promises to create good numerical libraries similar to NAG or NUMAL. I do wonder why this has never been concretized successfully, and any good and robust scientific computing library made available. For sure the Ada language doesn't pale before any other scientific computing language in my opinion.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find anything about it, which is indeed a bit surprising.

If it has a C interface, it is possible to write your own bindings to the routines you need. Just use the [interfacing pragmas](http://www.adaic.org/standards/95lrm/html/RM-B-1.html). The types defined in the package [Ada.Interfaces.C](http://www.adaic.org/standards/95lrm/html/RM-B-3.html) would also be of help. Getting things linking and tested on a custom binding can be a wee bit of a challenge though.

Also, it looks like recent versions of Gnat come with a [binding generator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Running-the-binding-generator.html) that can create Ada bindings for you out of C header files. There are six more such tools [available here](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Utilities&Title=Ada+Utilities), including one that works on [Windows COM DLLs](http://www.gnavi.org/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=GNATCOM&Title=GNATCOM) that I've heard good things about.

Comment: Thanks. I have started to use the C numerical library from Visual Numerics (www.vni.com). I need to give this a test with Ada. 1 vote up for all the info.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to use `lapack` from Ada. You do not need to call `Matlab` for that. `Lapcak` is the same library which `Matlab` uses as well.

Comment: Thanks. Yes indeed, Ada comes with lapack. I do not find it so easy though to interface it with Ada. Is there any information out there on the web with simple examples about how to do the interfacing?

Answer (score 1):

There are few packages under Ada.Numerics which perform the matrix and vector operations

Comment: More specfically, Ada 2005's Ada.Numerics.Generic_Real_Arrays for eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Sure, but the much simpler solution, using Ada.Numerics.Generic_Real_Arrays, was not available or known enough at the time.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to **Ada.Numerics.Generic_Real_Arrays**, there is **Generic_Real_Linear_Equations** with, notably, Cholesky and LU decomposition, available in the open-source library Mathpaqs [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mathpaqs/) or [here](https://github.com/zertovitch/mathpaqs).